# Deletion and rotation with array-based binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

```
class AST
{
private:
    TreeNode **a;       
    int capacity;        
public:                       
void deletenode(const int &i);
```

That's my AST tree class(TreeNode is an abstract class).

let's pretend a[t] is a[i]'s left child, after the call to deletenode(i), a[t] and its left child should be deleted while a[t]'s right child should become a[i]'s new left child.

I'm really clueless, I should have said "here's what I tried" but I'm going to say here's what I thought of :

1-Build a new tree from a[t]'s right child(and its children) and then inserting the new tree at left of a[i], I have a function to insert a tree to a tree but this is a very poor, slow algorithm.

2-Thought of some relation to apply on every node so that a[i]=a[f(i)] and then delete a[f(i)] but I didn't find any f(i) and there are some nodes which are unaffected by the delete.

What I need is the algorithm, nothing else, this as its name implies is for a compiler project, deletion is important for optimization, I need it to be based on an array because breadth-first pass algorithm is a lot simpler with it.

### A question similar to mine

[Delete operation in Array Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092545/delete-operation-in-array-binary-tree). However, it doesn't answer my question and does not say any thing about rotation.

And there are many questions about array-based binary trees but not about delete and rotate.

So is There a fast algorithm to do that ? Thanks for any help.

### PS

The root is a[0] not a[1]. so the left child of a[i] is a[2*i+1] and the right is a[2*i+2].